# Calling stored procedure from C# is not working

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_VISUALIZAR_PIS_PROCESSO_IMPORTACAO_DETALHE_HISTORICO
@DATA_HISTORICO DATETIME
, @SIGLA_ESTADO VARCHAR(2)
, @ANO_MES INT
, @SEMANA_MES INT   
, @CODIGO_LINHA_FICTICIA INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT  P.PROD_CD_PRODUTO
        , P.PROD_DS_PRODUTO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_NOTA_FISCAL
        , HIST.PIDH_NR_ORDEM
        , HIST.PIDH_NR_ITEM
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_PROCESSO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_PREV_BOOKING
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_CHEGADA_PORTO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_PREVISAO_EMBARQUE_ORDEM
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_LIBERACAO
        , ISNULL(HIST.PIDH_DS_CANAL, '-') AS PIDH_DS_CANAL
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_REFERENCIA
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_REMESSA
        , HIST.PIDH_IN_FATURAS_IMPORTACAO
        , HIST.PIDH_NM_FORNECEDOR
        , CASE WHEN HIST.PIDH_DT_NOTA_FISCAL IS NOT NULL THEN 'Sim' ELSE 'NãO' END AS INDICADOR_RECEBIDO
        , SUM(HIST.PIDH_QN_FATURA) AS PIDH_QN_FATURA
        , MAX(HIST.PIDH_QN_ORDEM) AS PIDH_QN_ORDEM
        , MAX(HIST.PIDH_QN_DIAS_DEMURRAGE) AS PIDH_QN_DIAS_DEMURRAGE
        , CASE WHEN HIST.PIDH_DT_LIBERACAO IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LIBERADO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_HISTORICO
        , HIST.DDT_NR_SEMANA_MES
        , HIST.DDT_NR_ANOMES
  FROM  PROCESSO_IMPORTACAO_DETALHE_HISTORICO HIST
        INNER JOIN ESTADO E ON E.ESTA_CD_ESTADO = HIST.ESTA_CD_ESTADO
        INNER JOIN PRODUTO P ON P.PROD_CD_PRODUTO = HIST.PROD_CD_PRODUTO
        INNER JOIN LINHA L ON L.LINH_CD_LINHA = P.LINH_CD_LINHA
        INNER JOIN LINHA_FICTICIA LF ON LF.LIFI_CD_LINHA_FICTICIA = L.LIFI_CD_LINHA_FICTICIA
        INNER JOIN VOLTAGEM V ON V.VOLT_CD_VOLTAGEM = P.VOLT_CD_VOLTAGEM
        INNER JOIN PRODUTO_COMERCIAL PC ON PC.PRCO_CD_PRODUTO_COMERCIAL = P.PRCO_CD_PRODUTO_COMERCIAL   
 WHERE  HIST.PIDH_DT_HISTORICO = @DATA_HISTORICO
  GROUP BY  P.PROD_CD_PRODUTO
        , P.PROD_DS_PRODUTO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_NOTA_FISCAL
        , HIST.PIDH_NR_ORDEM
        , HIST.PIDH_NR_ITEM
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_PROCESSO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_PREV_BOOKING
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_CHEGADA_PORTO
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_PREVISAO_EMBARQUE_ORDEM
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_LIBERACAO
        , HIST.PIDH_DS_CANAL
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_REFERENCIA
        , HIST.PIDH_CD_REMESSA
        , HIST.PIDH_IN_FATURAS_IMPORTACAO
        , HIST.PIDH_NM_FORNECEDOR
        , HIST.PIDH_DT_HISTORICO
        , HIST.DDT_NR_SEMANA_MES
        , HIST.DDT_NR_ANOMES
END
```

This procedure is working fine when I call from SQL Server Management Studio, but when I call from C# it doesn't work. I need of the output of this procedure, but I'm not having success.

The C# code is that:

```
object[] o = new object[5];
o[0] = dataHistorico;
        o[1] = filtro.SiglaEstado;
        o[2] = filtro.AnoMes;
        o[3] = filtro.SemanaMes;
        o[4] = linhaFiciticia;

string query = "exec USP_VISUALIZAR_PIS_PROCESSO_IMPORTACAO_DETALHE_HISTORICO @DATA_HISTORICO = {0}, @SIGLA_ESTADO = {1}, @ANO_MES = {2}, @SEMANA_MES = {3}, @CODIGO_LINHA_FICTICIA = {4}";
var r = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, o);
```

The output of this code is always -1, but when I execute from SQL Server it returns more than 10 thousand of records.

What's wrong? Someone can help me to fix that?

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution:

```
        string query = "exec USP_VISUALIZAR_PIS_PROCESSO_IMPORTACAO_DETALHE_HISTORICO";
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StringConexao"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);            
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query + " @DATA_HISTORICO = '" + dataHistorico.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', @SIGLA_ESTADO = " + filtro.SiglaEstado + ", @ANO_MES = " + filtro.AnoMes + ", @SEMANA_MES = " + filtro.SemanaMes + ", @CODIGO_LINHA_FICTICIA = " + linhaFiciticia, conn);

        command.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        command.Connection.Close();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        conn.Close();

        command.Connection.Close();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ProcessoImportacaoDetalhePISVO pi = new ProcessoImportacaoDetalhePISVO();

            string processo = row["PIDH_CD_PROCESSO"].ToString();
            string referencia = row["PIDH_CD_REFERENCIA"].ToString();

            pi.Processo = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(processo) ? processo : referencia;
            lista.Add(pi);
        }
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: What does `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` do?

Comment: Have you tried to pass parameters separetly? db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, dataHistorico, filtro.SiglaEstado, ...)

Comment: If you're using stored procedures, why aren't you using SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: @wudzik Yes, I've tried!

Comment: @Arran, this command calls the procedure.

Comment: The first thing I would do is run SQL Server Profiler against the database to see precisely how the stored proc is being executed. My guess is that there is something wrong with the date parameter.

Comment: @competent_tech I did this. If I copy the script of the SQL Server Profiler and executed the command on Management Studio and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use SqlCommand with your stored procedure. Try something like this.

```
string connectionString = "your connection string";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("USP_VISUALIZAR_PIS_PROCESSO_IMPORTACAO_DETALHE_HISTORICO", connection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter p1 = command.Parameters.Add("@DATA_HISTORICO", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                p1.Value = dataHistorico;

                SqlParameter p2 = command.Parameters.Add("@SIGLA_ESTADO", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                p2.Value = filtro.SiglaEstado;

                //.... continue for rest of parameters

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        //Read your values into some data structure
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used this idea but I did it in a different way. I'll update my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) just returns what SQL Server returns. If you want the number of rows return, then you can probably accomplish this by selecting the rowcount into a local variable in the SP and returning that from the stored procedure.

If your goal is to get the records from the SP, then you need to explore the database [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method and see which of the overloads applies to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteSqlCommand is for executing a "command" - which in ADO.NET doesn't return a resultset (those are called "queries"). Since it looks like you're using Entity Framework, you can either model it in the designer or use the SqlQuery method.